# For Scroll View Touch Events Is Not Working In Ios

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, uiwebview, uiscrollview

am working on PDF Viewer app for which i have loaded PDF in to my web view and i have added image view to my web view image is showing on web view perfectly but when am trying to move web view, image is not moving along with web view . so i have added image view to webview.scrollview  so image also moving with webview, but am facing the problem after adding image view to the webview.scrollview its touch events is not working.

can anyone suggest me how to resolve this problem... thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Have you added property userInteractionEnabled to YES for your ImageView?

Comment: Yes, I have added the userInteractionEnabled to YES , i need to move image from one location to another on webview.scrollview so am using touche events methods but its not working for webview.scrollview. if i use webview.scrollview.userinteractionenabled=no; touch events is working but if i use webview.scrollview.userinteractionenabled=yes; means touch events method is not calling.

Comment: In case you are touching links to test, PDF links don't work correctly in UIWebViews

Comment: which is the best way to load PDF in to ios app and should have the drawing features...

Comment: Maybe you can try Quicklook ? But i'm not sure about drawing.

Comment: Here is a link for Quicklook: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/UsingtheQuickLookFramework.html